# The connection was reset message with C# web app

Tags: c#, email, firefox, reset, server

I have a mass email web page that I created to send out emails.  It seemed to work till I tried it for 10,000 emails.  I currently have the send commented out, but I'm inserting a row for each email in my oracle database table.  All 10,000 email rows are inserted but the browser displays the following:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I have tried adding larger values for maxRequestLength and executionTimeout with the config file and it still shows this message.  I'm not sure how to pinpoint where and why the connection is reset.  What code would be beneficial for me to post?

Comment: Why do you have a web page that can send 10,000 emails?  Seems like this would be better for a server job.

Comment: It is on our web server and it sends the mail through an smtp server. I have to be able to track each email that goes out.

Comment: My point is you don't need a web page to do this.  This should be a scheduled process/job that runs nightly on your server.  i.e. Console application.

Comment: We only run this 2-3 times a year and the subject and message need to be entered manually.  Which I'm sure can be done in the console application.  So with a console application there is no need to return anything like with a web app so the rest won't happen?

Comment: You won't have the timeout issue with the browser if you do a console application.  Or you could rewrite your code to use ajax...

Comment: Rick thank you for the suggestion.  I'm going to try and work on a console application to see how it works.  How would AJAX work in this case?  I'm not sending anything back to the browser.  I'm just adding the subject and body of the email then clicking a button.  When it finishes there is nothing the browser needs to do. Thanks

Comment: With ajax you could send back the progress (10% complete.etc) and display it, but that might be more work than it's worth.